# Can I link to a .ejs-page from a .html-page?

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

I am making a webpage and I have been looking on stackoverflow on how to link to .ejs-files from a .html-file.

People are saying the following

**In index.html:**

```
<li><a href="/twitter">Twitter</a></li>
```

**In script.js:**

```
app.get('/twitter',function(req,res){
 res.render('twitter', { });
});
```

But it does not work for me. It says "Your file was not found". It works on localhost, but not when I first click on index.html and then click on twitter.ejs page from there. My code looks like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drvsa0va/3/).

twitter.ejs is in a view folders, while index is outside of this folder.

What is wrong?

Comment: You don't link directly to a view template. Those are returned in your models. So the appropriate way to do this would be to link to what is returned in your twitter model.

Comment: @kawnah Thank you for your reply, but I'm not sure what you mean by models? Do you mean the .html-file as a viewing template?

Comment: Oh wait - do you want to insert this directly into HTML? Or have this link to a seperate page?

Comment: @kawnah I have a index.html where I want to link to twitter.ejs. twitter.ejs has its own css-file that does not work when I put "views/twitter.ejs" in index.html, but it does not work at all without the .ejs extension.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is you're trying to link directly to a view template.

You need to create a route to a twitter controller that then calls your template. It would look something like this:

`router.get('/twitter', twitterController.twitter_view);`

Comment: Hm.. do you have any tutorials on this? I have `const app = express();` and then `app.get('/twitter',function(req,res){res.render('twitter', {});});`. I tried to change it to what you wrote, but twitterController is not defined. What should I define it as? Can't seem to find anything on this exact topic. Thanks for your reply again.

Comment: I used this one, it's really good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Tutorial_local_library_website

Comment: I understand what you mean by route now, but it still does not work. My code looks like this now: http://jsfiddle.net/drvsa0va/1/

Answer (score 0):

If your .ejs file is called "contact.ejs" as an example, then the route you're targeting may be something like "/contact".

1. First setup the contact route in your server code:

//Setting up the contact route
app.get("/contact", function (req, res) {

res.render("contact", {});
});

2. Update the href in the corresponding anchor tag to:
   href="/contact"

I am using expressJS and EJS for this example. So these must be setup first.